# Add and remove classes to a selector does not work

Tags: jquery

I want to have a div that shows/hides another div.

It is not possible to work with toggle, because at the end it must work with cookies (I take jquery.cookie.js) to remember the changes when the site is reload.
(I built a search-result with Drupal search API and give out some facets. but when I choose an item of a facet, the site is reload an some div on the site can be displayed or not and should remember their status).

Why doesn't this code work?

```js
$('.show').click(function(){

$('.inhaltetest').addClass('block1');
$('.inhaltetest').removeClass('none1');
$('.hideshow').addClass('hide');
$('.hideshow').removeClass('show');
});

$('.hide').click(function(){

$('.inhaltetest').addClass('none1');
$('.inhaltetest').removeClass('block1');
$('.hideshow').addClass('show');
$('.hideshow').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.none1 {display: none;}
.block1 {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="hideshow hide">Hide/Show</div>
<div class="inhaltetest block1">Inhalte</div
</div>
```

Comment: Update your `CSS` too, I will add a easier method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our Question, you want to hide/show another `div`. This is possible by `toggleClass`. If your `class` `show` and `hide` don't have any property you don't have to `toggle` them. Since `div` is already a `block-element` you shouldn't add `CSS` `display:block;`

```js
$(".hideshow").on("click", function(){
  $(".inhaltetest").toggleClass("none1");
});
```

```css
.none1 {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideshow hide">Hide/Show</div>
<div class="inhaltetest">Inhalte</div
</div>
```

Try this snippet and if it doesn't meet your requirement. Please leave a comment.

Comment: So many thanks! works perfectly for me! (i dont take the toggle-variation, because i must always know, what class is active, so i take the wider way, but works now great - and to now toggleclass is also nice).

Comment: @Stefan if it works, you can accept as a answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Why your code not working .. because you `add/remove` and toggle between the `hide` and `show` classes which used as a selector in the click event.. if you need it to work you can use `$(document).on('click','.hide',function(){` and `$(document).on('click','.show',function(){`
- It will be easier to use `.toggleClass()` with just one click event

```js
$('.hideshow').on('click', function(){
  $('.inhaltetest').toggleClass('block1 none1');
  $(this).toggleClass('hide show');
});
```

```css
.none1 {display: none;}
.block1 {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="hideshow hide">Hide/Show</div>
<div class="inhaltetest block1">Inhalte</div
</div>
```

And to be more specific and you have more than one button and need to toggle them

```js
$('.hideshow').on('click', function(){
  $('.inhaltetest').not($(this).next('.inhaltetest')).removeClass('block1').addClass('none1');
  $('.hideshow').not($(this)).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  $(this).next('.inhaltetest').toggleClass('block1 none1');
  $(this).toggleClass('hide show');
});
```

```css
.none1 {display: none;}
.block1 {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="hideshow show">Hide/Show</div>
  <div class="inhaltetest block1">Inhalte</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="hideshow hide">Hide/Show</div>
  <div class="inhaltetest none1">Inhalte</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi mohame-yousef,